# "Indirect" Excel function not working as intended on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

So I'm using this function in Excel, but when I try to use it in Google Sheets, the result isn't the same.

[image]

=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&D6:D8&"'!$F:$F"),D10))

Basically, I'm using this function to count the number of times "Pass" appears on Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3. It's all working as intended on excel, but when I use it in Google Sheets, it's only gonna search on the first sheet, "Sheet1" in this case. I've been trying to figure out a way to make it count on every sheets but it just doesn't work.

Comment: I messed up when adding a picture to my question and I can't edit. Here is what it looks like on excel : https://imgur.com/a/RuCyKFn

Comment: Perfect. I got the picture loaded in there now. I'm guessing this is an order of operations issue since you are nesting `indirect(<array>)` inside of a sumproduct(). I'm guessing Google Sheets is parsing the array for Indirect first, then slipping it up to Countif() then to Sumproduct. Where Excel is probably parsing the array for Sumproduct then working down. Not certain on that though since I'm unfamiliar with the inner workings of Google Sheets.

Comment: While it's more cumbersome you could get out of the array issue with: `=Countif(Indirect(D6 & "!F:F"), D10) + Countif(Indirect(D7 & "!F:F"), D10) + Countif(Indirect(D8 & "!F:F"), D10)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and for adding the picture! I was trying to avoid going with a separate function for each sheets as I will be adding more in the future. I'll be investigating to see if I can fix up the order of operations issue as you mentionned, otherwise, I'll back up with your solution. Thanks :)